# AWS restrict access to port

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications

Some advice please. We have an instance on AWS. It hosts a web app on a single server.  We would like to restrict access to the app (ports 80/443).  We can't simply restrict connections through the firewall to a range of white listed IP Addresses because we don't know where our users will be coming from or if they will have static addresses. They are not very tech aware and would most likely not connect if it is complicated.

Is Amazon virtual private cloud a solution or would another solution get us to where we want to be. We are a non profit org and will not be charging people so we would like to accomplish this within our budget.

Ideally we would provide individual logins/passwords that we can share with people that would grant them access to the url. We are not sure how this can be accomplished but we think that restricting access on a server must be possible and need some guidance on the approach. It is new to us.

Thanks for reading.

Howard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict access to the box over 80/443 using security groups. Then, restrict access to the application with user ids and passwords.

Comment: Only ports 80, 443, and 22 are allowed through security groups.  Unfortunately the application does not include access control to restrict unauthenticated viewers.  I'm interested to know if HTTP Basic Authentication can be incorporated into most any web site or if a VPN is required to restrict access to a web application in AWS. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need a VPN; HTTP basic authentication or forms authentication can be incorporated. Amazon also has a solution for user management, Cognito.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the HTTP Basic Authentication. Integrating it into Nginx looks straight forward.  Cognito seems really nice but it looks like I need some sort of API to use it as a front end for accessing the instance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris.  I got this working by combining Basic Authentication with HTTPS.